# Getting 400 error in response on Post request

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-400

My request function:

```
var cnt=(new Date().getTime());

function requestp(path, data, run)
{
cnt++;

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', path+'?'+data+'&cprv='+cnt, true);
request.setRequestHeader('cache-control', 'no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
request.setRequestHeader('expires', 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT');
request.setRequestHeader('pragma', 'no-cache');
request.addEventListener('readystatechange' ,function()
{
if ((request.readyState==4) && (request.status==200))
run( request.responseText);
}
);

request.send(data);

}
```

`path+'?'+data+'&cprv='+cnt` string is [here, in pastebin](https://pastebin.com/hcDc8MBU).

Running function with that parameters throws 400 response. I have been checking it for `\n`, `\r` symbols, but nothing. Another strings works well. Any ideas what’s wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There were some mistakes, which do not deal with http request, and the request function, that has edited earlier has mistake.

In case of post request, `open` method should get only path, and parameters should be passed to `send` method.

```
var cnt=(new Date().getTime());

function requestp(path, data, run)
{
cnt++;

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', path, true);
request.setRequestHeader('cache-control', 'no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
request.setRequestHeader('expires', 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT');
request.setRequestHeader('pragma', 'no-cache');
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"); //perhaps it is necessary 
request.addEventListener('readystatechange' ,function()
{
if ((request.readyState==4) && (request.status==200))
run( request.responseText);
}
);

request.send(data+'&cprv='+cnt);

}
```